# OSM download data

Tags: openstreetmap, data, qgis-2.18, download

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.18. I have OSM raster map opened.  I go to Vector/OpenStreetMaps/download data.  I have tried all three options in the dialog box.  My answer is always the same no data downloaded when I try to upload a smaller OSM map and data.dialog box

Comment: Are you running the latest LTR version QGIS 2.18.23? It might be an issue alredy fixed.

Comment: I'm running 2.18.23, I got the same issue as him yesterday when I did my screenshot

Comment: For some reasons, I still use 2.18.4 with no error. So it might be worth a bug report. Maybe some backporting spoiled it. Note that this feature is dismissed in QGIS 3 in favour of the QuickMapServices plugin.

Comment: QuickMapServices is for rasters. For vectors, you have to use QuickOSM

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I noticed the bug too.

[image: error message]

This is not a "no data" issue as you mentionned in your ticket. It's an error about bad request made to Overpass API.

When you have your dialog:

[image: wrong coordinates]

Switch to "manual" and remove extra characters on the right in each box until the "e".

[image: right coordinates]

This request will work.
Don't use the extent of your layer "OSM Standard", this is covering the whole planet. And unfortunately "From map canvas" is broken because it's using letters in parameters.

Comment: Your attempt is only halfway correct. The original scrennshot shows a map of Swellendam in South Africa, and the coordinates in the dialogue box are EPSG:3857 meters, not degrees. I have no idea how he got those, I get degrees as expected.

Comment: Ah yes indeed. Only half the solution. Shame on me, I was living in Swellendam.

Comment: I tried to download OSM of my area in Oregon.  It came up in degrees.                             top 43.4482, bottom 42.3668, left -124.783, right -121.77

Comment: sorry new to this site, I forgot how to upload pics. to show you my results

Comment: Thanks and my apology to all who help me through the question I had with downloads of OSM data.
I work for a county in Oregon in Search and Rescue.  I produce maps for volunteers, maps they are using in searches, rescues, and recoveries.  During the fire seasons our people need maps with addresses as the travel door to door doing notifications.  Qgis is new to me and I often use it in my work.  I have no formal training in mapping and learning as I go.

Comment: I use a county computer with all of its firewalls.  When I tried to download the OSM data on my personal computer it worked great the first time.  I now know there are things I cannot do with the county computer but must use my personal one.  Therefore, I am asking to close this question and at the same time thanks to all who help in this process.

Answer (score 1):

How did you load the OSM raster basemap in QGIS? I have always used the OpenLayers Plugin.

When I use that, and load the OSM basemap (without previously having added anything, so in a fresh new project), the map is automatically set to the **EPSG:3857, WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator** projection.

When I subsesequently open the **Download OpenStreetMap data** option, the dialog properly shows decimal degrees bounding box parameters (it seems to do an automatic translation from the Web Mercator projection, which of course has totally different coordinates).

I can subequently download data without any issues, I have done that dozens of times.

So, what CRS / projection is listed in your project in the map's properties?

[image: QGIS OpenStreetMap download data dialog]

Comment: Here is where I am at today; downling OSM of my area.  Version 2.18.22, Using OpenLayersPlugin/OpenStreetMap CRS EPSG:3857, Project Properties, Settings/CRS/EPSG:3857

Comment: Jerry, could you be more clear please? Are you saying that with those settings, you still cannot download data, and still see the errorneous coordinate display? The only difference that I currently see, is that I am still on QGIS 2.18.11. Did something get broken inbetween these versions (instead of fixed as it should be for bugfix releases X.X.n)...